# Right click on Catfish missing

Tags: search

I lost the context menu in Catfish on Xubuntu 18.04, right click did nothing.
Apparently a known bug in 14.4.4-1 and the fix was found on another forum.

....... this bug was fixed in the package catfish - 1.4.7-1

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fix (it worked) 
with this terminal-command :
CODE: SELECT ALL
sudo sed -e 's/"key-release-event" handler="on_catfish_window_key_press_event"/"key-release-event" handler="on_catfish_window_key_release_event"/' -i /usr/share/catfish/ui/CatfishWindow.ui
....... this bug was fixed in the package catfish - 1.4.7-1 but if your system hasn't updated to that version yet this will fix.